# Using GEKKO to solve ODE System with colinear equations due to initial conditions

Tags: python-3.x, ode, gekko

I am trying to solve the following ODE system representing a conical spouted bed reactor for the 6 unknowns namely the 4 velocities (us, ua, vs, va), the pressure p and the void fraction eps_s.
[image]

My initial conditions at z=0 are us = 24 m/s, ua = vs = va = 0 m/s, p = 360000 Pa and eps_s = 1.
However, due to my initial conditions the last two equations of the system get colinear at z=0 and all solvers I tried so far, inlcuding explicit and implicit solvers from MATLAB and Julia failed to solve the system. Which is why I wanted to try and see if I could solve my system using GEKKO.

Unfortunately, GEKKO failed too and I wanted to know if it is due to the system itself or if I made a mistake during my implementation.

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0., 0.2,10)

# parameters
D0 = m.Param(0.06)
D_s = m.Param(0.04)
alpha_c = m.Param(1.152)
eps_a = m.Param(0.45)
eta_g = m.Param(1e-5)
rho_g = m.Param(1.3)
spheri = m.Param(1.)
d_p = m.Param(0.003)
rho_s = m.Param(2360.)
g = m.Param(9.81)

# variables and initial conditions
u_s = m.Var(value=24.)
u_a = m.Var(value=0.)
v_s = m.Var(value=0.)
v_a = m.Var(value=0.)
p = m.Var(value=360000.)
eps_s = m.Var(value=1.)

# additional
z = m.Var(value=m.time)
D_c = D0 + 2.*z*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5)

Re_p_a = m.Intermediate(rho_g * m.abs(v_a-u_a) * d_p * eps_a / eta_g)
C_D_a = m.if3(-1*Re_p_a, 24./Re_p_a * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_a**0.687), 0)
beta_Ergun_a = 150. * (1.-eps_a)**2 * eta_g / (eps_a*(d_p*spheri)**2) + 1.75*rho_g*(1.-eps_a)*m.abs(u_a-v_a) / (d_p*spheri)
beta_Wen_a = 0.75 * C_D_a * rho_g*(1.-eps_a)*m.abs(u_a-v_a) / (d_p*spheri) * eps_a**-2.65
phi_g_a = m.atan(150*1.75*(0.2-(1.-eps_a))) / np.pi + 0.5
beta_a = (1.-phi_g_a)*beta_Ergun_a + phi_g_a*beta_Wen_a

Re_p_s = m.Intermediate(rho_g * m.abs(v_s-u_s) * d_p * eps_s / eta_g)
C_D_s = 24./Re_p_s * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_s**0.687)
beta_Ergun_s = 150. * (1.-eps_s)**2 * eta_g / (eps_s*(d_p*spheri)**2) + 1.75*rho_g*(1.-eps_s)*m.abs(u_s-v_s) / (d_p*spheri)
beta_Wen_s = 0.75 * C_D_s * rho_g*(1.-eps_s)*m.abs(u_s-v_s) / (d_p*spheri) * eps_s**-2.65
phi_g_s = m.atan(150*1.75*(0.2-(1.-eps_s))) / np.pi + 0.5
beta_s = (1.-phi_g_s)*beta_Ergun_s + phi_g_s*beta_Wen_s

# equations
m.Equation(-1.*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*u_a.dt() - D_s**2 /(eps_a) * (eps_s*u_s.dt() + u_s *eps_s.dt()) - 4. *u_a * D_c *m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) == 0)
m.Equation(-1.*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*v_a.dt() - D_s**2 /(1.-eps_a)* ((1.-eps_s)*v_s.dt() - v_s *eps_s.dt()) - 4. *v_a * D_c *m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) == 0)

m.Equation(-1.* u_s.dt() *u_s*eps_s*rho_g - p*eps_s.dt() - eps_s *p.dt() - beta_s*(u_s-v_s) - g*eps_s*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)
m.Equation(-1.* v_s.dt() *v_s*(1.-eps_s)*rho_s + p*eps_s.dt() - (1.-eps_s)*p.dt() + beta_s*(u_s-v_s) - g*(1.-eps_s)*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)

m.Equation(-2.*rho_g*u_a*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*u_a.dt() - 4.*rho_g *u_a**2 *D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) + rho_g*u_a*D_s**2 /eps_a * (eps_s*u_s.dt() + u_s*eps_s.dt()) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*p.dt() - 4.*p*D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*beta_a*(u_a-v_a) /eps_a - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*g*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)
m.Equation(-2.*rho_s*v_a*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*v_a.dt() - 4.*rho_s *v_a**2 *D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) - rho_s*v_a*D_s**2 /(1.-eps_a) * ((1.-eps_s)*v_s.dt() - v_s*eps_s.dt()) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*p.dt() - 4.*p*D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) + (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*beta_a*(u_a-v_a) /(1.-eps_a) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*g*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)

# solve
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()
m.cleanup()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The system of equations solves successfully if the `m.if3()` statement is removed. With the `m.if3()` statement, the solver determines that the set of equations is infeasible.

```py
#C_D_a = m.if3(-1*Re_p_a, 24./Re_p_a * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_a**0.687), 0)
C_D_a = 24./Re_p_a * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_a**0.687)
```

I recommend checking the `m.if3()` conditions to make sure a zero value should be used for `C_D_a` if `Re_p_a<0`. The `Re_p_c` Reynolds number calculation does not have the same condition. The values of `Re_p_a` in the final solution also appear to be very small but positive so you may not need the `m.if3()` condition.

```
Re_p_a = [0.0, 1.9048571431e-11, 1.4395918458e-11, 2.9893167235e-12, 
          8.6407817168e-13, 9.5340975304e-13, 9.020616017e-13, 
          4.5442810476e-12, 3.2721611684e-12, 1.4398004515e-12]
```

There may also be a problem with solver convergence tolerances for `m.options.RTOL` (default=`1e-6`) with such small numbers. Here is a complete script that solves successfully:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0., 0.2,10)

# parameters
D0 = m.Param(0.06)
D_s = m.Param(0.04)
alpha_c = m.Param(1.152)
eps_a = m.Param(0.45)
eta_g = m.Param(1e-5)
rho_g = m.Param(1.3)
spheri = m.Param(1.)
d_p = m.Param(0.003)
rho_s = m.Param(2360.)
g = m.Param(9.81)

# variables and initial conditions
u_s = m.Var(value=24.)
u_a = m.Var(value=0.)
v_s = m.Var(value=0.)
v_a = m.Var(value=0.)
p = m.Var(value=360000.)
eps_s = m.Var(value=1.)

# additional
z = m.Var(value=m.time)
D_c = D0 + 2.*z*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5)

Re_p_a = m.Intermediate(rho_g * m.abs(v_a-u_a) * d_p * eps_a / eta_g)
#C_D_a = m.if3(-Re_p_a+1e-10, 0, 24./Re_p_a * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_a**0.687))
C_D_a = 24./Re_p_a * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_a**0.687)
beta_Ergun_a = 150. * (1.-eps_a)**2 * eta_g / (eps_a*(d_p*spheri)**2) + 1.75*rho_g*(1.-eps_a)*m.abs(u_a-v_a) / (d_p*spheri)
beta_Wen_a = 0.75 * C_D_a * rho_g*(1.-eps_a)*m.abs(u_a-v_a) / (d_p*spheri) * eps_a**-2.65
phi_g_a = m.atan(150*1.75*(0.2-(1.-eps_a))) / np.pi + 0.5
beta_a = (1.-phi_g_a)*beta_Ergun_a + phi_g_a*beta_Wen_a

Re_p_s = m.Intermediate(rho_g * m.abs(v_s-u_s) * d_p * eps_s / eta_g)
C_D_s = 24./Re_p_s * (1. + 0.15*Re_p_s**0.687)
beta_Ergun_s = 150. * (1.-eps_s)**2 * eta_g / (eps_s*(d_p*spheri)**2) + 1.75*rho_g*(1.-eps_s)*m.abs(u_s-v_s) / (d_p*spheri)
beta_Wen_s = 0.75 * C_D_s * rho_g*(1.-eps_s)*m.abs(u_s-v_s) / (d_p*spheri) * eps_s**-2.65
phi_g_s = m.atan(150*1.75*(0.2-(1.-eps_s))) / np.pi + 0.5
beta_s = (1.-phi_g_s)*beta_Ergun_s + phi_g_s*beta_Wen_s

# equations
m.Equation(-1.*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*u_a.dt() - D_s**2 /(eps_a) * (eps_s*u_s.dt() + u_s *eps_s.dt()) - 4. *u_a * D_c *m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) == 0)
m.Equation(-1.*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*v_a.dt() - D_s**2 /(1.-eps_a)* ((1.-eps_s)*v_s.dt() - v_s *eps_s.dt()) - 4. *v_a * D_c *m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) == 0)

m.Equation(-1.* u_s.dt() *u_s*eps_s*rho_g - p*eps_s.dt() - eps_s *p.dt() - beta_s*(u_s-v_s) - g*eps_s*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)
m.Equation(-1.* v_s.dt() *v_s*(1.-eps_s)*rho_s + p*eps_s.dt() - (1.-eps_s)*p.dt() + beta_s*(u_s-v_s) - g*(1.-eps_s)*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)

m.Equation(-2.*rho_g*u_a*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*u_a.dt() - 4.*rho_g *u_a**2 *D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) + rho_g*u_a*D_s**2 /eps_a * (eps_s*u_s.dt() + u_s*eps_s.dt()) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*p.dt() - 4.*p*D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*beta_a*(u_a-v_a) /eps_a - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*g*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)
m.Equation(-2.*rho_s*v_a*(D_c**2 -D_s**2)*v_a.dt() - 4.*rho_s *v_a**2 *D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) - rho_s*v_a*D_s**2 /(1.-eps_a) * ((1.-eps_s)*v_s.dt() - v_s*eps_s.dt()) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*p.dt() - 4.*p*D_c*m.tan(alpha_c*0.5) + (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*beta_a*(u_a-v_a) /(1.-eps_a) - (D_c**2 -D_s**2)*g*(rho_s-rho_g) == 0)

# solve
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()
m.cleanup()
```

One other thing to watch out for is the `m.abs()` functions that are not continuously differentiable for the gradient-based solvers. Using `m.abs3()` may help with finding a solution. As with any application, it is a good idea to verify your expected solution with a sample time-point.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed the if statement and the abs(),. Even though the solver finishes "successfully", the variables don't change at all with some oscillation if I increase the number of evaluation points. Also is my implementation of the diameter D_c changing with the height correct ?